# Angular UI Modal loading before boolean is evaluated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have radio buttons to answer items in a quiz. If a radio button is selected the user then selects the next button with the Enter Key to open the modal allowing the proceed modal appears to evaluate if the radio has been selected or not. My problem after the user selects the radio answer and hits return the boolean `ngApp.Review.Quiz.items[ngApp.currentQuizItem.index].complete;` is remaining false when inside of the resolve property even though it's true. Is there anyway to pass this boolean value to the ProceedCtrl function so that it can be evaluated properly in the resolve property? I can't use `$timeout`.

---

#### modalService.js

```
//Proceed Modal
var ModalProceedCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, answered) {

    $scope.answered = answered;

    $scope.proceedOk = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.proceedCancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };

  };

  var ProceedCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {
    
      $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'proceedModal',
        controller: ModalProceedCtrl,
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
          answered: function() {
             return ngApp.Review.Quiz.items[ngApp.currentQuizItem.index].complete;
          }
        }
     });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
          $scope.doProceed();
          return false;
        }, function () {
            return false;
    });

 };
    
};
```

Comment: it's not really clear where you pass answered after the resolve, can you make a fiddle or a plunker of your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as part of the scope of the controller like so:

```
$scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'proceedModal',
    controller: ModalProceedCtrl,
    backdrop: 'static',
    scope: angular.extend($rootScope.$new(false), {
        answered: ngApp.Review.Quiz.items[ngApp.currentQuizItem.index].complete;
    }
}
```